# Column related issue in Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I jsut used the fullcalendar. When i add multiple resource, i gets some cosmetic issue. 
see this link http://prntscr.com/6rx76y

Add the below code 10 times:

```
{
      'id': 'resource3',
      'name': 'Resource 3',
      'className': ['red']
    }],
```

Kindly help me, how to resolve that issue.

You can test from the below link :

http://plnkr.co/edit/cX9dH8eTjKaddJ0Gpw21?p=preview

Comment: What browser? It works on chrome for me.

Comment: Chrome. Just add above the code 10 times. so that you can able to reproduce the scrolling issue and the column issue.